# Exceptions in accessing HDFS file system in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I tried accessing HDFS file with Java API as the following code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;

public static void main(args[]) {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));

    try {
        Path path = new Path("hdfs://mycluster/user/mock/test.txt");
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(path.toUri(), conf);
        if (fs.exists(path)) {
            FSDataInputStream inputStream = fs.open(path);
            // Process input stream ...
        }
        else
            System.out.println("File does not exist");
    } catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
```

An exception occurred at `FileSystem.get(path.toUri(), conf)` saying that `Couldn't create proxy provider class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider` which is caused by `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials`.

I did not find much information about the error. Is the issue due to the wrong API (`org.apache.hadoop.hdfs` instead of `org.apache.hadoop.fs`)?

Answer (score 0):

1)Do you have the hadoop-hdfs-.jar available in your classpath?

2)How are you downloading the dependencies? Maven/Manual/Other

3)Could you please provide the stacktrace?

Comment: 1. Yes, both hadoop-common.jar and hadoop-hdfs.jar. 2

Comment: ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider class should be available in your hadoop-hdfs.jar. Could you please verify whether it's available.
If it's available, then check if that jar is added in your build path.
If both the above case is addressed, then it shouldn't cause NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: The Class is available in the hadoop-hdfs 2.7.2 jar. The Play framework resolved and downloaded the dependencies correctly. What should I do to verify if the jar is in the build path?

Comment: Maybe the problem lies in "Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials"?

Comment: Credentials should also be available under hadoop-common jar...
Play framework is new to me. So let me check that as well to see how it's resolving and building the jar.